# Crop an image and upload with jQuery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file, jquery-file-upload

I'm using JQuery File Upload con UploadHandler, this:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php
I upload well the images with fileupload, but now I need to modify them before uploading. I'm using croppie.js:
http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/
I'm modifying 'fileuploadadd' method in this way:

```
.bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    $(e.target).fileupload('option', 'url', uploads_base_url + '?f=' + $(e.target).attr('folder'));
                var acceptFileTypes = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
                if ($(e.target).attr('data-accept_file_types') != '' && '' + $(e.target).attr('data-accept_file_types') != 'undefined')
                    acceptFileTypes = new RegExp($(e.target).attr('data-accept_file_types'), 'i');
                if (data.originalFiles[0]['name']) {
                    var fileExt = '.' + data.originalFiles[0]['name'].split('.').pop();
                    if (!acceptFileTypes.test(fileExt)) {
                        alert('Formato non ammesso');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        data.context = $("<div id='cropper'></div>").croppie({
                            viewport: {
                                width: 300,
                                height: 300,
                                type: 'circle'
                            }
                        })
                                .insertAfter("#dragArea");
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            data.context.croppie('bind', {
                                url: e.target.result
                            });
                        };
                        $("<div><button>Taglia</button></div>").insertAfter("#cropper")
                                .click(function () {
                                    $("#cropper").croppie('result', {format: 'jpeg'}).then(function (resp) {
                                        var blob = new Blob([window.atob(resp.split(",")[1])],{type:"image/jpeg"});
                                        data.files[0] = new File([blob], data.originalFiles[0]['name'].split(".")[0]+".jpeg");
                                        data.originalFiles[0] = data.files[0];
                                        data.submit();
                                        $("#cropper").remove();
                                        $(this).remove();
                                    });
                                });
                    }
                }
                //fixFileuploadValue(e.target, data.files[0].name);
            });
```

Click on cut button, the file is uploaded, but it is encoded in a different way than fileupload file. How can I download in the same way the image cropped?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: @gabn88 I saw your fork from jquery file upload but you did not provide a demo or working sample. Can you push a working example?

Comment: @estevex see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create new blob file. Just add type option is : **blob**. Like this:

```
$("#cropper").croppie('result', {format: 'jpeg', type: 'blob'}).then(function (resp) {                                        
                                    data.files[0] = new File([resp], data.originalFiles[0]['name'].split(".")[0]+".jpeg");
                                    data.originalFiles[0] = data.files[0];
                                    data.submit();
                                    $("#cropper").remove();
                                    $(this).remove();
                                });
```

Comment: Wow, that's so much easier. Thanks for this improvement :)

Answer (score 0):

@Estevex

We ended up using cropper.js without jQuery fileupload in this case. Code below:

```
/* SCRIPTS TO HANDLE THE CROPPER BOX */
var $image = $("#image");
var cropBoxData;
var canvasData;
$("#modalCrop").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
  $image.cropper({
    viewMode: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1/1,
    minCropBoxWidth: 200,
    minCropBoxHeight: 200,
    ready: function () {
      $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
      $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
    }
  });
}).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
  cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
  canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
  $image.cropper("destroy");
});

// Enable zoom in button
$(".js-zoom-in").click(function () {
  $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
});

// Enable zoom out button
$(".js-zoom-out").click(function () {
  $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
});

/* SCRIPT TO COLLECT THE DATA AND POST TO THE SERVER */
$(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
  var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
  $("#id_avatar-form-x").val(cropData["x"]);
  $("#id_avatar-form-y").val(cropData["y"]);
  $("#id_avatar-form-height").val(cropData["height"]);
  $("#id_avatar-form-width").val(cropData["width"]);
  $("#formUploadAvatar").submit();
});

</script>
```

Good luck and if you have any success with jQuery fileupload, don't forget to give something back to the community :)

Comment: Thanks @gabn88. I will do my best to make it work with jQuery fileupload and show that to the community.

Comment: @Estevex were you able to intgrate cropper JS with jquery file upload

Comment: @GayanKavirathne not really sorry, we went in another direction as timeline was short